# Develop the next function:$f(x)=\frac{4x+53}{x^2-x-30}$ into power series, Find the radius on convergence and find $f^{(20)}(0)$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Develop the next function:$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{4x+53}{x^2-x-30}$ into power series, Find the radius on convergence and find $f^{(20)}(0).$

For the first part:

$\displaystyle\frac {4x+53}{(x-6)(x-5)}\to\frac {4x+53}{(x-6)(x+5)}=\frac{A}{(x-6)}+\frac{B}{(x+5)}=\frac{7}{(x-6)}+\frac{-3}{(x+5)}=\frac{7}{-6(1-\frac x6)}+\frac{-3}{5\left(1-(-\frac x5)\right)}$

$\displaystyle=-\frac76\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(\frac x6\right)^n}-\frac35\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac x5\right)^n$

Now i'm having trouble with finding the radius of convergence and $f^{(20)}(0)$.

What does $f^{(20)}(0)$ means? 20 derivatives and $x=0$? That means i should find a some-kind of pattern and then place $x=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
1) For the radius of convergence: do you know what is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$? if so, find the radius of convergence for each series separately. Then, the radius of convergence for the sum will be the minimal (do you see why?)
2) You just found the taylor series around $x=0$. The general form of Taylor series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$. So, what is $f^{(20)}(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

When you have

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

then

$$f^{(k)}(0) = k! \, a_k$$

You know $a_{20}$:

$$a_{20} = -\frac{7}{6} \frac{1}{6^{20}} - \frac{3}{5} \frac{1}{5^{20}}$$